# What is the true meaning of "I want to eat your pancreas"?

Tags: japanese-language, i-want-to-eat-your-pancreas

Ok, I think that most people have heard of this strange title of the anime movie which is due to come out... I've read the novel and the manga. But I just don't understand what the title actually means. The characters mention it at the start and at the end... I know that it shouldn't be taken literally but can anyone explain me the meaning of the title?

Comment: Wait... *why* shouldn't it be taken literally?

Comment: I want gain from whatever you offer or have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, this relates to the fact that in Japanese culture, and various other Asian cultures as well, mothers use a phrase along the lines of '*I will eat up your disease X, so that you can get all better...*' to their children; the title here refers to the fact that,

> Haruki wants Sakura to get all better from the disease she is suffering, which is some sort of pancreas disease

Comment: Never watched it, so don't know for sure, but: isn't what you hid in the spoiler markup pretty much [the show's premise](https://myanimelist.net/anime/36098/Kimi_no_Suizou_wo_Tabetai)? Is it much of a spoiler?

Comment: Fair enough, yeah, the synopsis gives it away as well..l